# React user testing with Jest executes test before BeforeEach method finishes

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am currently trying to test a react app using React testing library and Jest. This is a snippet of my code:

```
const renderComponent = async () => {
  component = render(
      <Component
        ... props
      ></Component>
  ).container

  return waitFor(() =>
    expect(
      component.querySelector(#some-element)
    ).toBeInTheDocument(),
  ).then(() => {
      console.log("done with method")
      return "good to go"
  })
}

beforeEach(async () => {
  return renderComponent().then(() => {
    console.log("done")
    return "done with before each"
  })
})

test('should test work', async () => {
  const element = getById(component as HTMLElement, 'element-id')
  userEvent.type(element!, "hello")
  // this test fails
  expect(mockFunction).lastCalledWith("hello")
})
```

My problem is not that my test fails, but the order of execution of the test suite. In my console, the console.log messages print out in this order:

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.123 s

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.  
 console.log
    done with method

  console.log
    done with before each
```

Why is the test failing before the logic in the beforeEach finishes? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know exactly what the issue is, but it seems like it might be returning out of order due to the async method passed to `beforeEach`.

Comment: Do you think the method should not be async? I just tried removing the async keyword and unfortunately that did not do anything. The tests should run after the promise in the  `beforeEach` method resolves, as stated in the Jest docs: "Runs a function before each of the tests in this file runs. If the function returns a promise, Jest waits for that promise to resolve before running the test."

Comment: Try to keep your assertions inside the `test` block and not in the `beforeEach`. In this case call `await renderComponent()` directly in your test.

Answer (score 0):

Since `renderComponent` is async, running it returns *immediately* without executing any code in the function.

You should await it, so it blocks the completion of `beforeEach` until `renderComponent` is done.

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  await renderComponent().then(() => {
    console.log("done")
    return "done with before each"
  });
});
```